# What is wrong with my Lucky name Number python code

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, pycharm

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
name = name.lower()
luckynumb = 0
firstnamenumb = 0  
surnamenumb = 0  

number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
row1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]  
row2 = ["j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"]  
row3 = ["s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"] 

for letter in name:  
    if letter == "a" or letter == "j" or letter == "s=":  
        luckynumb += 1  

if letter == "b" or letter == "k"or letter == "t":
    luckynumb += 2  
if letter == "c" or letter == "l"or letter == "u":
    luckynumb += 3  

if letter == "d" or letter == "m"or letter == "v":
    luckynumb += 4  

if letter == "e" or letter == "n"or letter == "w":
    luckynumb += 5  

if letter == "f" or letter == "o"or letter == "x":
    luckynumb += 6 

if letter == "g" or letter == "p"or letter == "y":
    luckynumb += 7 

if letter == "h" or letter == "q"or letter == "z":
    luckynumb += 8  

if letter == "i" or letter == "r":
    luckynumb += 9 

surnamenumb = - luckynumb  

while int(firstnamenumb) > 9: 
    split = list(str(firstnamenumb))  # it will
    firstnamenumb = int(split[0]) + int(split[1])  
    print(firstnamenumb)  

while int(surnamenumb) > 9:  
    split = list(str(surnamenumb))  # it will
    surnamenumb = int(split[0]) + int(split[1])  
    print(surnamenumb) 

luckynumb = firstnamenumb + surnamenumb  

for luckynumb in range(1, 5, 9):  #
    print(luckynumb)  
if int(luckynumb) == 1:  
        print("Natural Leaders")  

elif int(luckynumb) == 2:  
    print("Natural Peacemakers") 

elif int(luckynumb) == 3:  
    print("Creative and Optimistic")  

elif int(luckynumb) == 4:  
    print("Hard Workers")  

elif int(luckynumb) == 5:  
    print("Value Freedom") 

elif int(luckynumb) == 6:  
    print("Carers and Providers")  

elif int(luckynumb) == 7:  
    print("Thinkers")  

elif int(luckynumb) == 8:  
    print("Have Diplomatic Skills") 

elif int(luckynumb) == 9:  
    print("Selfless and Generous")  

else: 
    print("Error. Please try again")
```

What is wrong with this code. no matter what you type in it only give the same 1 answer.

Comment: Your indentations are wrong. `surnamenumb = - luckynumb ` might give you an error. `while int(firstnamenumb) > 9:` will never happen as it is 0 when you hit it. That might be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your purposes:

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
name = name.lower()
luckynumb = 0
firstnamenumb = 0  
surnamenumb = 0  

number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  
row1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]  
row2 = ["j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"]  
row3 = ["s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"] 

for letter in name:  
    if   letter == "a" or letter == "j" or letter == "s":   luckynumb += 1  
    elif letter == "b" or letter == "k" or letter == "t":   luckynumb += 2
    elif letter == "c" or letter == "l" or letter == "u":   luckynumb += 3
    elif letter == "d" or letter == "m" or letter == "v":   luckynumb += 4
    elif letter == "e" or letter == "n" or letter == "w":   luckynumb += 5
    elif letter == "f" or letter == "o" or letter == "x":   luckynumb += 6
    elif letter == "g" or letter == "p" or letter == "y":   luckynumb += 7
    elif letter == "h" or letter == "q" or letter == "z":   luckynumb += 8
    elif letter == "i" or letter == "r":                    luckynumb += 9

surnamenumb = - luckynumb  

while int(firstnamenumb) > 9: 
    split = list(str(firstnamenumb))  # it will
    firstnamenumb = int(split[0]) + int(split[1])  
    print(firstnamenumb)  

while int(surnamenumb) > 9:  
    split = list(str(surnamenumb))  # it will
    surnamenumb = int(split[0]) + int(split[1])  
    print(surnamenumb) 

luckynumb = firstnamenumb + surnamenumb  

luckynumb = abs(luckynumb) % 9

print(luckynumb)

if   int(luckynumb) == 0:   print("Natural Leaders")  
elif int(luckynumb) == 1:   print("Natural Peacemakers") 
elif int(luckynumb) == 2:   print("Creative and Optimistic")  
elif int(luckynumb) == 3:   print("Hard Workers")  
elif int(luckynumb) == 4:   print("Values Freedom") 
elif int(luckynumb) == 5:   print("Careers and Providers")  
elif int(luckynumb) == 6:   print("Thinkers")  
elif int(luckynumb) == 7:   print("Has Diplomatic Skills") 
elif int(luckynumb) == 8:   print("Selfless and Generous")  
else:                       print("Error! Please try again")
```

Also, check out the PEP-8 style guide for python. It will help I promise:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Modulo 8 will result in values from 0-7.  In this case I think you mean modulo 9.  (Which makes sense, because the letters are split into 9 groups here)

Answer (score 1):

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ").lower().split()
firstname, *middle, lastname = name

first_num = sum(((ord(letter) - 97) % 9) + 1 for letter in firstname)
sur_num = sum(((ord(letter) - 97) % 9) + 1 for letter in lastname)

while first_num > 9:
    first_num = sum(map(int, str(first_num[:2])))
while sur_num > 9:
    sur_num = sum(map(int, str(sur_num[:2])))

lucky = first_num + sur_num
print("Your lucky number is {}".format(lucky))
```

Here's my attempt to tidy up your code. I've simplified the calculation of each letters value.  `ord` gets the ordinal values of each number, then we get the remainder of division by 9, and add 1 so our results don't start at 0.

Then we add the first two digits of our number together until it is less than 9.  If you instead wanted to sum all the digits, just remove the `[:2]`.

As an addendum, are you sure you're supposed to sum the surname and firstname lucky numbers after reducing them to below 10?  I think it would make more sense to do so first and then reduce the sum.